# cant add app icon in appropriate size in android studion

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am working on my first android app,The problem I am having is that the app icon is very very small.

I tried to add an icon by follow this:  `File > New > Image Assets > select launcher icon > choose image file`.

I put icon size 512X512. It placed them in the different MipMap folders in different size but when I launch my app i see that my icon is smaller than the others.

[image]

It is much smaller than the others (my app is 'roomates').

Comment: check the icon image, maybe it has some white space around

Comment: try adjusting the padding when you create the icon

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the extra white-space/transparency around your app icon.

Additionally follow the below stated guidelines for optimum results. Drop respective icon (based on icon size) in the respective `mip-map` folder.

```
Format - *.PNG

48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store)
```